# Run window.addEventListener('load' ...) only once

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there is any way to run `window.addEventListener('load' ...)` only the first time the specific page is loaded.

I tried just setting a flag called `loaded` to `false`, and only run the code inside the `eventListener` if `loaded === false`. Then once it's run, I set loaded to `true`. But does not work, still runs every time.

Can I perhaprs remove the eventListener once its run?

Comment: You mean, you want it to run only the first time a user navigates to that page?

Comment: @CertainPerformance correct

Comment: You'll need to set a cookie or local storage value to remember whether you've been there before. A simple variable won't be retained across page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Easy way: you can use web storage that is if it's supported. Something like:

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem("listenerLoaded")) {
  window.addEventListener('load'...)
  localStorage.setItem("listenerLoaded", true);
}
```

A bit tedious work would be using:
2. cookie(still browser needs support etc).
3. ajax and hold session

Answer (score 1):

Keep a `localStorage` item that contains an array corresponding to all pages that have been loaded so far. Only attach the listener if that page isn't stored in `localStorage` yet. For example:

```
const { href } = window.location;
const alreadyLoaded = JSON.parse(localStorage.loaded || '[]');
if (!alreadyLoaded.includes(href)) {
  alreadyLoaded.push(href);
  localStorage.loaded = JSON.stringify(alreadyLoaded);
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // rest of your code
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the once property to true and it will run only once (doesn't work with Internet explorer)

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#:%7E:text=Copy%20to%20Clipboard-,JavaScript,-const%20outer%20%20%3D%20document)

```
const once = {
  once : true
};

window.addEventListener('load',callback, once);
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible a  a new execution context will be created every time that page loads.
You can try something like localStorage to save the state.

> LocalStorage API helps you to save data which can be accessed later.it is an Object which can be used to access the current origin's local storage space.

For more info visit:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a value in local storage once listener gets loaded then read that value before adding it again.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("isLoaded")) {
  window.addEventListener('load' ...)
  localStorage.setItem("isLoaded", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using removeEventListener is a good option:

```
var callback = function(){
   ...
}
window.removeEventListener('load',callback);
window.addEventListener('load',callback);
```